# Add if data is new Or Update when data is different angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to Update the data instead of adding (create) a new data when the image is changed (image is in base64)

I had also followed: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zeuk/12/ like what i tried to do below but i had tried my best at it but it **update** is not working. There are no errors.

Just for your information i am using ngCropper. https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper

**EDIT: updated controller code**

Angular code

```
      app.controller("ProductAddCtrl", function($scope, $timeout, $resource, Product, Products, $location, Cropper) {
        $scope.product = {item_name: '', price: '', category: ''}
        var file, data;

        $scope.saveImage = function(dataUrl) {
          if (!file || !data) return;
           if ($scope.product.currentImage){
              Cropper.crop(file, data).then(Cropper.encode).then(function(dataUrl) {
                ($scope.preview || ($scope.preview = {})).dataUrl = dataUrl;
                  Product.update({id: $scope.product.id }, {product: { item_name: $scope.product.item_name, category: $scope.product.category, price: $scope.product.price, item_image: dataUrl, filename: file.name}},function(){
            //  $location.path('/');
                console.log($scope.product)
                }, function(error) {
                  console.log(error)
                });
              });
            } else {
              Cropper.crop(file, data).then(Cropper.encode).then(function(dataUrl) {
                ($scope.preview || ($scope.preview = {})).dataUrl = dataUrl;
                  Products.create({ product: { item_name: $scope.product.item_name, price: $scope.product.price, item_image: dataUrl, filename: file.name }}, function(){
                  // $location.path('/');
                  }, function(error){
                    console.log(error)
                  });
              })
            }
          }

          $scope.onChange = function() {
            if ($scope.product.currentImage) {
              $scope.product.item_image = $scope.product.currentImage.item_image;
              $scope.product.filename = $scope.product.currentImage.filename;
            } else {
              $scope.product = {};
            }
          }
  });
```

Angular Template file

```
<div class="content-push">
  <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFile(this.files[0])" ng-class="{'has-error' : productForm.item_image.$invalid}" ng-model="product.currentImage" ng-change="onChange" required>
    <br />
    <div ng-if="dataUrl" class="img-container">
      <img ng-if="dataUrl" ng-src="{{dataUrl}}" width="300" height="300"
          ng-cropper
          ng-cropper-proxy="cropperProxy"
          ng-cropper-show="showEvent"
          ng-cropper-hide="hideEvent"
          ng-cropper-options="options">
    </div>
    <br />
      <button ng-click="preview()" class="btn btn-success">Show preview</button>
      <button ng-click="zoomin()" class="btn btn-default">Zoom In</button>
      <button ng-click="zoomout()" class="btn btn-default">Zoom Out</button>
      <!-- <button ng-click="saveImage()" class="btn btn-default">Save</button> -->
      <input type="submit" value="{{ product.currentImage.item_image ? 'Update' : 'Save' }}", class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveImage()">
      <div class="preview-container">
        <img ng-if="preview.dataUrl" ng-src="{{preview.dataUrl}}" width="100" height: "100">
      </div>
      <select name="sellCategory" class="form-control" id="sellCategory" ng-model="product.category" required>
        <option ng-repeat="option in categories.availableCategories" value="{{option.category}}">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" ng-model="product.item_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name" required>
      <input type="text" ng-model="product.price" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Price" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `Cropper` defined? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: "but update is not working" ... maybe you can tell us what is actually happening? Do you get an error? Or in the `if/else` statement it always goes down the path for creating a new object?

Comment: @SunilD. no errors, i am confused on the example in the fiddle above and trying to add it into my controller.

Comment: @eric it is ngCropper - https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper

Answer (score 0):

I grasped the concept wrong.

Let's say i have multiple file upload feature in, instead of configuring angularjs to upload file one by one (via PUT request), i would select each file in base64 format (for preview) and then input the fields (like price, category and name of item) on the client side in angularjs instead of POSTing the PUTting each and every data.

So after everything on client side is set with image preview (i intend to have four) and data, then i would save (POST) it to the backend instead.

Thanks to everyone who looked at my question.